# Where can I ask for specific statistical data?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

For example I have this question: "How many books are published in the Irish language every year?" and I would like to know if there is any site where I can ask this. [I tried on Linguistics SE](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/20162/irish-books-printed-every-year) and it didn't work.

Does it fit into the [Open Data Stackexchange](http://opendata.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: Do note that not every question belongs somewhere on Stack Exchange.

Comment: What, is there a set number?  You have to get in under the deadline, or wait to get published the next year?  And what happens if they fall short--do they just fill a book with the Gaelic version of lorem ipsum?

Comment: I don't think it fits Stack Exchange. The University of Dublin (Trinity) has a deposit library: they hold a copy of all books published in Ireland. On the assumption that the number of Irish-language books published outside Ireland is negligible, they'd have the data in their catalogue. And librarians tend to be helpful.

Answer (score 7):

> Where can I ask for specific statistical data?

Nowhere. Not in Stack Exchange for sure, and probably not any forum or Q&A site.

Stack Exchange sites have clear scope and focus, which by itself can't be too broad. For example, there is no SE site just for books as it would be too broad, but question about Science Fiction or Fantasy books can be asked in [Science Fiction & Fantasy site](//scifi.stackexchange.com/), and question about cooking books can be asked in [Seasoned Advice site](//cooking.stackexchange.com/).

Taking your example, "How many books are published in the Irish language every year?" needs research in several areas of expertise:

- Books
- Irish language

So no Q&A site or forum is likely to accept it. (As long as it's not "Ask Me Anything" kind of forum)

Comment: Thanks. Open Data SE is not good for such questions? A proposal for general statistical data SE site has any chance to be accepted?

Comment: @Joe well, it does have [several questions about books](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/search?q=books), but I believe that asking there "How many books are published in the Irish language every year?" will also be closed. Worth to try asking in their per site meta.